# reproduce a specific table

Tags: tables, tabulary

I am stucking to reproduce this triangle : [image]

This is what I did :

```
    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \center
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|c c c c c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{developpement year j} \\
    \hline
    Accident year & 1 & 2 & 3&4&j&... & $J$ \\
    \hline \hline
    1 & & & & & \\
    2 & & & & & \\
    3 & & & & & \\
    4 & & & & & \\
    j & & & & & \\
        ... & & & & & \\
        $I$ & & & & &   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

some help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome! Please post code for a minimal but complete document showing what you've tried (with `tabulary`?).

Comment: Related: [Stepped table in booktabs](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/433930).

Comment: @AlanMunn Should this be drawn as a table at all, do you think?

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. Could you make your snippet compilable, please?

Comment: @cfr In this case it's not hard to do as a table.

Comment: @AlanMunn Not hard, but I find they get messy. By which I mean, they get hard (for me) to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, boldline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
      \begin{tabular}{V{2}cV{2}*{10}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8mm}}V{2}}
         \hlineB{2}
        \multirowcell{2}{Accident \\ Year $i$} & \multicolumn{10}{cV{2}}{Development Year $j$}\\
         & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & j & &\dots & & J \\
                     \hlineB{2}
        1 & \multicolumn{10}{cV{2}}{}\\
        \cline{11-11}
        2 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{10-10}
        3 & \multicolumn{7}{c}{$C_{ij}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & & \\
        \cline{9-9}
        4 & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{(Observations)} & \multicolumn{2}{c }{} & \\
        \cline{8-8}
         & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c }{} & \\
        \cline{7-7}
        $I-j$ & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} & \\
        \cline{6-6}
         & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} & & \multicolumn{5}{cV{2}}{$C_{ij}$} \\
        \cline{5-5}
        $ I-2 $ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & & & \multicolumn{5}{cV{2}}{(to be predicted)} \\
        \cline{4-4}
        $ I-1 $ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{} & \\
        \cline{3-3}
        $ I $ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{} & \\
         \hlineB{2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the oddness at the right edge on the rows numbered 2 and 3?

Comment: @AlanMunn: I had forgotten to take into account the external rules should be thicker (that's the `V{2}` instead of a plain `|`.  I'll fix it in a moment. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: @AlanMunn But if I was going to do it as a table, I'd definitely get Bernard to do it :-).

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to use Ti*k*Z as this is more of a diagram than a table. Surely you will get different solutions, but here's one way with a `matrix of math nodes`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \matrix (T) [matrix of math nodes, draw, nodes={minimum width=5ex, anchor=mid, text height=2ex, text depth=.5ex}, nodes in empty cells]
  {
    \text{Accident} & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \text{year } i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & j & & \dots &  & J \\
    1 & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    2 & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    3 & & & & C_{i,j} & & & & & &  \\
     & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    I-j & & & & & & & & & &  \\
     & & & & & & & & & &  \\
     & & & & & & & & C_{i,j} & &  \\
    I-2 & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    I-1 & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    I & & & & & & & & & &    \\
  };
  \node at (T-1-1.mid -| T-1-6) [anchor=mid] {Development year $j$};
  \draw (T.west |- T-2-1.south) -- (T.east |- T-2-1.south) (T.north -| T-1-1.east) -- (T.south -| T-1-1.east)
  (T.south -| T-12-2.east) \foreach \i/\j in {12/3,11/4,10/5,9/6,8/7,7/8,6/9,5/10,4/11} { |- (T-\i-\j.north east) } -- (T-4-11.north -| T.east);
  \node [anchor=north] at (T-5-5.south) {(observations)};
  \node [anchor=north] at (T-9-9.south) {(to be predicted)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The matrix is named `T` and the cells are then `T-1-1`, `T-1-2`, `T-1-3` and so on.

[image: non-table-type diagram with tablish features in Ti*k*Z]